# If $f$ is an immersion and $g$ is a submersion, then is $g \circ f $ a local diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I don't think so; the counter example I had in mind was $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3 , f(x,y) = (x,y,x)$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2, g(x,y,z) =(x-z, y-z)$. Is my example right?

Comment: Or how about just $\mathbb{R}^1 \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{R}^2 \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{R}^1$ where $f(t)=(0,t)$ and $g(x,y)=x$.

Comment: Yes that would do fine too. Actually the problem I was attempting wanted one example involving those particular spaces??I just wanted to see if I had got it right. Thanks for your example too. But is mine alright??

Comment: If $f$ is an immersion and $g$ is a submersion, $g \circ f$ might not even be a map between manifolds of the same dimension...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential of $f$ (at any point of $\mathbb{R}^2$) has standard matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right].$$

As this matrix has trivial null space, the differential is injective at every point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so $f$ is an immersion.

The differential of $g$ (at any point of $\mathbb{R}^3$) has standard matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{array}\right].$$

As this matrix has rank two, the differential is surjective at every point of $\mathbb{R}^3$ so $g$ is an submersion.

However, the differential of $g\circ f$ (at any point of $\mathbb{R}^2$) has standard matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0\\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right].$$

As this matrix is singular, $g\circ f$ is not a local diffeomorphism. So your example does work.

---

Note, if $f : L \to M$ is an immersion and $g : M \to N$ is a submersion, then as you've demonstrated, $g\circ f$ may not be a local diffeomorphism. However, if one adds the condition that $L$, $M$, and $N$ have the same dimension, then $g\circ f$ is a local diffeomorphism (because $f$ and $g$ are local diffeomorphisms).

Comment: I had not put this much thought into it. Thanks a lot, especially for the last bit.